# "the one with the red door on the right" / "on the right, with the red door"

Tags: sentence-construction

> My house is **the one with the red door on the right**.
>
> My house is **on the right, with the red door**.

Are both sentences idiomatic and do they have the same meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine.  There are potentially a couple of different meanings of the first sentence. It could mean "my house has a red door and my house is on the right" or it could mean "my house has a red door and the door is on the right".

In context there would be no ambiguity.  If you were saying this you would be looking at your house, or a picture of your house, and everything would be clear.  In context, both are acceptable sentences.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You wrote that the first sentence could have two meanings and one meaning is "my house has a red door and my house is on the right". I suppose in that context there would be a comma: "My house is the one with the red door **,** on the right." Is that right?

Comment: That's right, or rather there would be a rhythmic and intonation pattern that is represented in writing by the insertion of a comma. These are very much spoken expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the second sentence as follows:

My house is on the right, the one with the red door.

Because there are a number of houses on the right and you're specifying which one is yours.

The first sentece is grammatically correct, but I personally prefer the one I just revised.